# sql show date between start date and end date

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how I can compare a birthday date between a start date and end date.

For now I use this:

```
select *
from users
where dayofyear(birthday) between dayofyear(start_date) and dayofyear(end_date);
```

the problem is if `start_date = 2011-12-01` and `end_date = 2012-01-01` then I get no results.

If the user birthday is `1931-12-12` any year, it must be in the query result.

For now i get no result.

someone have a hint to resolve this kind of issue? Thanks.

Comment: What data type is `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080207/mysql-select-all-data-between-two-dates)

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to get a couple of days advance notice of a birthday?

Comment: Thanks for reply. What i want to do, is to show result between a start_date and end_date based on birthday if user birthday are 1931-12-15 and start_date are 2011-12-01 and end_date are 2012-01-01 the user must be in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a little ugly but it accounts for **all birthdays that occur in the time span between start_date and end_date**. If the time span is greater than a year then it basically returns everyone because everyone has a birthday somewhere in that time span. If it is less than a year but start and end are on different years **it uses two between clauses** to capture both the start time to the end of the year and the start of the year to the end time. This query also **assumes that start_date <= end_date**.

As long as you have an **index on DAYOFYEAR( birthday )** this query is performant despite it's appearance.

```
SET @start_date = '2011-12-01';
SET @end_date = '2012-01-01';

SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DAYOFYEAR( birthday )
  BETWEEN IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 1, 1,
    IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 0,
      IF( DAYOFYEAR( @start_date ) <= DAYOFYEAR( @end_date ), 1,
        DAYOFYEAR( @start_date ) ),
      DAYOFYEAR( @start_date ) ) )
      AND IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 1, 366,
            IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 0, 366,
              DAYOFYEAR( @end_date ) ) )
  OR DAYOFYEAR( birthday )
  BETWEEN IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 1, 1,
    IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 0, 1,
      DAYOFYEAR( @start_date ) ) )
         AND IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 1, 366,
               IF( YEAR( @end_date ) - YEAR( @start_date ) > 0,
                 IF( DAYOFYEAR( @start_date ) <= DAYOFYEAR( @end_date ), 366,
                   DAYOFYEAR( @end_date ) ),
                 DAYOFYEAR( @end_date ) ) );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, i never expected we can use condition like that in a sql query.