# Mysql query from and to

Tags: mysql, sql

Say,i've to select a value from today to next sunday. How to input date?

Is there any keyword like FROM = 26-12-2001 TO = 30-12-2001

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080207/mysql-select-all-data-between-two-dates

Comment: Several good options already posted: my comment on use of BETWEEN: has to do with choice of data types.  If you have a date/time field then when using between be careful of times and ensure what you enter is truly between that date/time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) for this

`WHERE YourDate BETWEEN '26-12-2001' AND '30-12-2001'`

although other common comparison operators can be used as well

`WHERE YourDate >= '26-12-2001' AND Yourdate < '31-12-2001'`

*Note the use of **31**/12/2001 when using the lesser then comparison operator*

Comment: The BETWEEN operator can cause real trouble with an end date in a comparison range when you're working with DATETIME data items.  It's best to use the second alternative.

Comment: @OllieJones - Would that be MySQL specific? I haven't had any troubles using BETWEEN with DATETIME on SQL Server (yet).

Comment: MySQL dates are specified YYYY-MM-DD, not DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: No, the between problem is not mySQL-specific.  If your timestamps contain both a date and a time (that is, they mention times of day other than midnight), then you'll have the issue.  For example. Timestamp 2011-12-26-17-45-00 is not BETWEEN 2011-12-25 AND 2011-12-26 (it's after 2011-12-26).  But 2011-12-26-00-00-00 is in that range.  True in all SQL systems, because BETWEEN is inclusive.  I've been burned by this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `between`.  In your case it would `between date1 and date2`

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
 WHERE your_tables_date_column 
 BETWEEN date1 and date2
```

Account for time if recorded with:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(your_tables_date_column, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') 
  /* Oracle trunc(col) equivalent */
 between date1 and date2
```

It works for strings too, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
 WHERE lower(last_name)
 BETWEEN 'smith' AND 'webster'
```

and for numbers e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
 WHERE height
 BETWEEN 1 and 3 /* meters, i.e. exclude kids */
```

and you can also use the negative, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
 WHERE lower(last_name)
 NOT BETWEEN 'smith' AND 'webster'
```

btw the literal answer to your questions is something like:

```
SELECT * from tbl where date_field BETWEEN
CURDATE() AND 
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (8 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=1, 8, DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY) AS NEXTSUNDAY  

/* Watch for performance issues with indexes when using functions on columns */
```

Comment: +1  It'd be wise to note that `FUNC(col) BETWEEN a AND b` generally means that the SQL engine cannot use an index on `col`.