# select users who their (timeStamped)birthday is X days later

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, date-arithmetic

I store birthday of my Users as Unix timestamp format(an integer number) in MySQL Database.

Now I want to send an email to users that their birthday is 30 days later.

I know that below SQL Code is to select users who their birthday is today :

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthday),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
```

but I don't know how to change it for my purpose.

I googled too much and found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226062/mysql-query-to-get-birthdays-for-next-10-days) on SO But all answers are based on **DATE** formatted birthday while my birthday field is based on **timeStamp** created by **time()**.

have you any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`datediff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   members 
WHERE  DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthday), NOW()) <= 30
```

Comment: i run this code But this error occured : FUNCTION DATE_DIFF does not exist

Comment: @ahmad that's a stupid typo, sorry about that. It's supposed to be `datediff`, not `date_diff` (edited and fixed).

Comment: yes it works fine. of course because i want to select users who their birthday is exactly 30 days later must user = operator instead of <=