# Selecting events between dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all events that are 'active' in a specifc time range.

This is how my table looks like

```
+---------------+------------------+----------------+
|    cmde_eid   | cmde_edate_start | cmde_edate_end |
+---------------+------------------+----------------+
```

I have two dates for this select, and I need to get all events that are active in the time range or a part of the time range.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you research this at all perhaps try the mysql docs or even google mysql select between dates ?  Go do some research and try it first then if you fail come back and ask questions

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080207/mysql-select-all-data-between-two-dates) could give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

***like this:***

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN cmde_edate_start AND cmde_edate_end
```

Comment: hey jmail, thanks for you'r reply. I need to select a range with two dates. So alle events happing betweem date A and B.

Comment: what you want, i can't understand,.. you should that  much of information only show..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table name
WHERE cmde_edate_start > '0000-00-00' AND cmde_edate_end < '0000-00-00'
```

You could also use the MYSQL between

```
SELECT *
FROM table name
WHERE (cmde_edate_start BETWEEN '0000-00-00' AND '0000-00-00') AND (cmde_edate_end BETWEEN '0000-00-00' AND '0000-00-00')
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

You could even use a mix of the two. These are just two quick example of checking between dates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in this case a event starting on

2014-02-03 until 2014-02-15 wont show up if i need to get events from 2014-02-01 until 2014-03-03