# Can't get all dates of a month in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I want to make a program that will show the attendances of an employee in one month. I can do that if just show the day that an employee was present, but i want to show the dates when an employee doesn't present (absence). 
I have MySQL Query like this

```
SELECT x.Tanggal
        , TIME(a.EventTime) AS TimeIn
FROM
(SELECT  Tanggal FROM (
SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-05-01', INTERVAL n5.num*10000+n4.num*1000+n3.num*100+n2.num*10+n1.num DAY ) AS Tanggal FROM
(SELECT 0 AS num
   UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4
   UNION ALL SELECT 5
   UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7
   UNION ALL SELECT 8
   UNION ALL SELECT 9) n1,
(SELECT 0 AS num
   UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4
   UNION ALL SELECT 5
   UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7
   UNION ALL SELECT 8
   UNION ALL SELECT 9) n2,
(SELECT 0 AS num
   UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4
   UNION ALL SELECT 5
   UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7
   UNION ALL SELECT 8
   UNION ALL SELECT 9) n3,
(SELECT 0 AS num
   UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4
   UNION ALL SELECT 5
   UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7
   UNION ALL SELECT 8
   UNION ALL SELECT 9) n4,
(SELECT 0 AS num
   UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4
   UNION ALL SELECT 5
   UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7
   UNION ALL SELECT 8
   UNION ALL SELECT 9) n5
) a
WHERE (Tanggal BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31')) x
LEFT JOIN VW_AttendanceIN a ON DATE(a.EventTime)=x.Tanggal
WHERE a.EmployeeID='90443'
AND (DATE(a.EventTime) BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31')
GROUP BY x.Tanggal
```

But, the result just give the present date like this

Result:

```
|   Tanggal  |  TimeIn  |
| 2014-05-01 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-02 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-05 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-06 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-07 | 08:00:00 |
```

The 3rd and 4th weren't listed
i want the result like this

```
|   Tanggal  |  TimeIn  |
| 2014-05-01 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-02 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-03 |   NULL   |
| 2014-05-04 |   NULL   |
| 2014-05-05 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-06 | 08:00:00 |
| 2014-05-07 | 08:00:00 |
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Comment: `AND (DATE(a.EventTime) BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31')` where makes it an inner join and probably move it to the joining clause.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it gives the same result if i remove that clause

Comment: could you please provide the table structures and some data I think its similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300303/mysql-single-table-select-last-7-days-and-include-empty-rows/23301236#23301236 I answered earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You need to replace this:

```
LEFT JOIN VW_AttendanceIN a ON DATE(a.EventTime)=x.Tanggal
WHERE a.EmployeeID='90443'
AND (DATE(a.EventTime) BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31')
```

with the following:

```
LEFT JOIN VW_AttendanceIN a ON DATE(a.EventTime)=x.Tanggal AND a.EmployeeID='90443'
```

### Reason

References to a joined table in the `WHERE` clause filters out final result set rows without matching rows from the joined table, i.e. it does not allow `a.EmployeeID` or `a.EventTime` to be `NULL`. It's not the case if one places these references in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` because it filters out not matching rows from the joined table and not from the final result set.

Comment: It's fix my problem, but i have a question. why my previous query doesn't give the same result? which one is the problem?

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation, it's give me much more experience