# Select all dates between two dates not using a table (generate list of dates)

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get all dates between two dates without using any MySQL table

Something like:

```
SELECT date BETWEEN '2012-02-10' AND '2012-02-15'
```

that would result in this:

```
out put date list
2012-02-10
...
2012-02-15
```

Comment: A loop in a procedure would do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of dates between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: Check this answer I gave recently I saved dated in a tabe, you can just use the select part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944750/create-a-temporary-table-with-dates/26944861#26944861

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Here is the query:**
This query gives proper result in both the databases : `MariaDB` & `MySQL`.

```
SELECT ADDDATE('2012-02-10', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
FROM (
SELECT a.a
FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
) a
JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
WHERE 
@i < DATEDIFF('2012-02-15', '2012-02-10')
```

Comment: hi @kruti-patel, thank you for this query. I created a store procedure from it with ease, I would kindly ask you to explain the logic behind this query. Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi @MatijaBaric, From clause will create combination values and select clause will start from startdate and will increment date by 1 everytime till the difference between two dates is not achieved.