# PrestoDB: select all dates between two dates

Tags: sql, presto

I need to form a report which provides some information per each date within dates interval.

I need to have it within a single query (can't create any functions or supporting tables).

How can I achieve that in PrestoDB?

**Note:** There are lots of vendor specific solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function) and even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969081/select-all-dates-between-two-dates-not-using-a-table-generate-list-of-dates). But none of them satisfies my need as they either don't work in Presto or use tables/functions.

To be more precise here is an example of query:

```
WITH ( query to select all dates between 2017.01.01 and 2018.01.01 ) AS dates
SELECT 
  date     date, 
  count(*) number_of_orders
FROM dates dates
LEFT JOIN order order
  ON order.created_at = dates.date
```

Comment: Can you provide some example SQL to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: @IkeWalker added an example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the Presto [`SEQUENCE()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) function to generate a sequence of days as an array, and then use [`UNNEST`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) to explode that array as a result set.

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT date_array AS DAY
FROM UNNEST(
      SEQUENCE(
        cast('2017-01-01' AS date), 
        cast('2018-01-01' AS date), 
        INTERVAL '1' DAY
      ) 
    ) AS t1(date_array)
```

Comment: Really helpful!

Comment: What's the purpose of the CROSS JOIN? Is there really any joining going on here?