# MySQL: How to get records even when no record on the date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting number of visits every day for generating a chart. Even when there are zero records, I want to get the record with count 0.

I am planning to create a table which will contain every day, and when fetching - data will join with this table and get count of the records from visit table. Is there any other way to do the same in mySQL?

### Visit Table with Sample Data

```
Date       | ........  
----------------------
01/11/2014 | --------
03/11/2014 | --------
```

I want results even for 02/11/2014 with count 0. If I group by date - I will get count only when records exists on a particular date.

Comment: Why cant the code that calls this db or shows on screen show 0 or default information when there is no record?

Comment: Why not use a date column and group by each day?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: I want to have record with 0 count for each date even when there is no record. So when I group by a date column will not get record when no record on the date.

Comment: try a case statement

Comment: @tgkprog I am getting the record in an array and passing it directly to a charting library and don't want to manipulate the data in JavaScript.

Comment: you need to generate a date table see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates and then left join your table to this table.

Comment: check this it one of my previous answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300303/mysql-single-table-select-last-7-days-and-include-empty-rows/23301236#23301236

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to read in between lines of your question... Sort of game where I write the question and the answer :-/

You have a table (`my_stats`) holding two fields, one is the date (`my_date`) the other is a integer (`my_counter`).

By some mean, you will need a table holding a list of all dates you want to use in your output.
This could be done with a temp table... (but not all hosting solution will allow you this) the other is to build it up on the fly, using a view or a stored procedure.
Then you will LEFT JOIN this table/view/stored procedure/etc... to your table `my_visits` based on the date field.
This will output you all dates, and when there won't be a match in mour `my_visits` you'll have a NULL value.  ( `IFNULL(my_visits.my_counter, 0)` will give you a 0 (zero) when there is no matching value.

inspiration:
[Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates) +
[How to get list of dates between two dates in mysql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query) and a nice solution here that needs  no loops, procedures, or temp tables [generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

Based on that last link, here we go...

first a sample table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_stats`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_stats` (
  `my_date` date NOT NULL,
  `my_counter` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `my_stats` (`my_date`, `my_counter`) VALUES
('2017-11-01', 2),
('2017-11-02', 3),
('2017-11-03', 5),
('2017-11-05', 3),
('2017-11-07', 7);
```

And now a working exemple `BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-09'`

```
SELECT date_range.date                AS the_date, 
       IFNULL(my_stats.my_counter, 0) AS the_counter 
FROM (
    SELECT a.date 
    FROM (
        SELECT Curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) day 
                   AS date 
            FROM (
                SELECT 0 AS a 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 1 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 2 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 3 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 4 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 5 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 6 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 7 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 8 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT 9
                ) AS a 
                CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT 0 AS a 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 1 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 2 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 3 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 4 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 5 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 6 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 7 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 8 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 9
                ) AS b 
                CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT 0 AS a 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 1 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 2 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 3 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 4 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 5 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 6 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 7 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 8 
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT 9
                    ) AS c
                ) AS a 
    WHERE  a.date BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-09'
    ) AS date_range 
   LEFT JOIN my_stats 
          ON( date_range.date = my_stats.my_date ) 
ORDER  BY the_date ASC
```

Output

```
+------------+-------------+
| the_date   | the_counter |
+------------+-------------+
| 2017-11-01 |           2 |
| 2017-11-02 |           3 |
| 2017-11-03 |           5 |
| 2017-11-04 |           0 |
| 2017-11-05 |           3 |
| 2017-11-06 |           0 |
| 2017-11-07 |           7 |
| 2017-11-08 |           0 |
| 2017-11-09 |           0 |
+------------+-------------+
```