# totals by month even for if there is a missing month

Tags: php, mysql

just a quick one, hopefully....

i am after getting some totals (sales value) by month from only a single table.

**The problem i have is:**
If there are no sales for a month, the month is of course not being returned in the results. Is there a way i can do this in a single query so if there were no sales in i.e "January 2015" the result would return "0.00 - January - 2015"

The basic SQL i currently have is:

```
SELECT SUM(p.PaymentAmount) AS Total, MONTHNAME(p.PaymentDate) AS Month, YEAR(p.PaymentDate) AS Year
FROM tPayment p
WHERE p.PaymentType = 2
GROUP BY YEAR(p.PaymentDate), MONTH(p.PaymentDate)
```

i cant think of how to do this without selecting the date range in php and then querying each month and year... this just seems messy... so i would like to know if i can do this in a single query.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can add a row for January with 0 in the sales field.

Comment: Would it be a problem to fill in any blanks at the PHP side?

Comment: Consider [nested queries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm).

Comment: Maybe a month table with `left join` to the payment table?

Comment: This looks to be what you're doing, but isn't a simple query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600863/mysql-monthly-sale-of-last-12-months-including-months-with-no-sale

Comment: do you need it just for one year? 2014? 2015? or there are many years?

Comment: Thanks all. After looking at all the options, it was after all better to do this in php and not try to make a single query.... thanks for the advice, it is greatly appreciated and useful.!!!

Answer (score 1):

you should create yourself a separate table containing at dates such as

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (
    `uid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `datestamp` DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and fill it

```
INSERT INTO dates (datestamp)
SELECT ADDDATE('2015-01-01', INTERVAL SomeNumber DAY)#set start date
FROM (SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100+d.i*1000 AS SomeNumber 
    FROM integers a,  integers b, integers c, integers d) Sub1
WHERE SomeNumber BETWEEN 0 AND (365 * 3)#3 years
```

then you can join against it

```
SELECT SUM(p.PaymentAmount) AS Total, MONTHNAME(p.PaymentDate) AS Month, YEAR(p.PaymentDate) AS Year
FROM tPayment p
LEFT OUTER JOIN dates d
    ON d.datestamp = CAST(p.PaymentDate AS DATE)
WHERE p.PaymentType = 2
GROUP BY YEAR(p.PaymentDate), MONTH(p.PaymentDate)
ORDER BY d.datestamp DESC;
```

regardless of if I fatfingered the queries here, the concept should hold up for you

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be my first choice method for accomplishing this task, but for the sake of providing multiple alternatives I offer this if you're trying to keep it all in MySQL and avoid creating an additional table.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.PaymentAmount) AS Total, 
    MONTHNAME(p.PaymentDate) AS Month, 
    YEAR(p.PaymentDate) AS Year
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS m UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 12
) AS months
OUTER JOIN tPayment p
    ON MONTH(p.PaymentDate) = months.m
WHERE p.PaymentType = 2
GROUP BY YEAR(p.PaymentDate), MONTH(p.PaymentDate)
```

I think it'd be easier to check against it in some quick PHP code after you run the query.

As suggested by [Jon B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182179/totals-by-month-even-for-if-there-is-a-missing-month/28182318#28182318) Creating a *months* table and joining against that would shorten and clean the query up quite a bit.  If you're trying to keep it all in your MySQL query I personally would choose his method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in your table for all months -- but the `where` clause is filtering out all the rows from one or more months -- you can try conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.PaymentType = 2 THEN p.PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS Total,
       MONTHNAME(p.PaymentDate) AS Month, YEAR(p.PaymentDate) AS Year
FROM tPayment p
GROUP BY YEAR(p.PaymentDate), MONTH(p.PaymentDate)
```

This isn't guaranteed to work (it depends on the data).  But if it does, it is the simplest way to solve this problem.

Comment: that would work with the current data, but only because there will be at least one form of PaymentType. but it would not work for me if there was not a single payment in any month (although this would never happen), so i would be relying on chance, which may not be good practice for me.... (i dont know why the down vote, seemed a reasonable suggestion/option to me... i have had the same happen to some of my questions in the past.... we all have to learn somewhere.....)

Comment: @Ford . . . That is explicitly explained in the answer.  This is just a simpler way of getting what you need, which might be possible depending on the data being used.