# List grouped data by month including months in which there are no results

Tags: mysql

Hello community The following query adds the occurrences of each activity state and then groups them by month

```
select
    date_format(date_created, '%b') month,
    month(date_created) pivot,
    sum(case when a.state = 'created' then 1 else 0 end) created,
    sum(case when a.state = 'notified' then 1 else 0 end) notified,
    sum(case when a.state = 'confirmed' then 1 else 0 end) confirmed,
    sum(case when a.state = 'approved' then 1 else 0 end) approved,
    sum(case when a.state = 'authorized' then 1 else 0 end) authorized,
    sum(case when a.state = 'attended' then 1 else 0 end) attended,
    sum(case when a.state = 'canceled' then 1 else 0 end) canceled,
    count(a.id) as total
from activities a
group by 1 order by pivot desc;
```

So I get the following result

[image]

I would like to add to this result the months in which there is no data and auto-complete the sums of state with zeros

[image]

I share this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0efcf/4)

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27601967) to a similar scenario but I can not understand how I could apply it to the case that I present to you

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use date table(subquery) and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select
    s.name month,
    s.m pivot,
    sum(case when a.state = 'created' then 1 else 0 end) created,
    sum(case when a.state = 'notified' then 1 else 0 end) notified,
    sum(case when a.state = 'confirmed' then 1 else 0 end) confirmed,
    sum(case when a.state = 'approved' then 1 else 0 end) approved,
    sum(case when a.state = 'authorized' then 1 else 0 end) authorized,
    sum(case when a.state = 'attended' then 1 else 0 end) attended,
    sum(case when a.state = 'canceled' then 1 else 0 end) canceled,
    count(a.id) as total
from (SELECT  1 m, 'Jan' AS name 
      UNION SELECT 2, 'Feb' 
      UNION SELECT 3, 'Mar'
      UNION ...) s
LEFT JOIN activities a
  ON s.m = month(date_created)
  --AND s.y = year(date_created)   -- if needed 
group by 1
order by pivot desc;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0efcf/8/0)**

Comment: Thank you very much. It's just the result I was looking for.

Comment: @user615274 Please note that if you have data from many years you need to add 3rd column with year to avoid aggregation data from 2 different years.

Comment: Could you develop your comment, please.

Comment: @user615274 For example you have data from `JAN 2017` and `JAN 2016`. If you use `month(created_date)` only then both `JAN` will be aggregated as one group.

Comment: I believe that this case is effectively addressed in the database, I avoid the aggregation message grouping by month and pivot `group by 1, 2`. Do you think that in long term is a correct solution?