# MYSQL SELECT QUERY show all dates between, even if data not present with count=0

Tags: mysql, database

> Below is the **query** i have written to **fetch the order count** with status=1 for **last week**.

```
  SELECT count(*) as order_count,
         DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d-%b-%Y') as order_date,
         status 
    FROM customer_order 
   WHERE date(order_date) >= curdate() 
                              - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
     AND date(order_date) < curdate() 
                              - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY 
     AND status=1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y%m%d'),
         status
```

> I am getting **result only for the dates present in the table**. I need all the dates with **count = 0**  **if data is not present** for particular date.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300303/mysql-single-table-select-last-7-days-and-include-empty-rows/23301236#23301236

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c1.order_date,'%d-%b-%Y') AS order_date
  FROM customer_order AS c1
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(c1.order_date,'%d-%b-%Y') 
                  IN ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c2.order_date,'%d-%b-%Y') as order_date2
                         FROM customer_order AS c2
                        WHERE date(DATE_FORMAT(c2.order_date,'%d-%b-%Y')) >= curdate() 
                                - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
                          AND date(DATE_FORMAT(c2.order_date,'%d-%b-%Y')) < curdate() 
                                - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY 
                          AND c2.status=1
                     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE_FORMAT(c2.order_date,'%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y%m%d'),
                              c2.status
                       HAVING count(*)=0
                     )
```

Comment: getting unknown column order_date2

Comment: What are you trying to find?

Comment: i want the records with count for date with status =1 and if data is not present for particular date the count should be 0 and date should be present

Comment: But do these dates exist in `customer_order` ?

Comment: Please, give us some example data and the expected result.