# MySQL retrieve records 10 days before and 10 after the given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the records from a MySQL table based on given date.

For example, `2014-10-11` is the given date, then I need records 10 days before and records 10 days after the given date.

Ex: `where Date-10 days AND date+10 days`.

Comment: That's great. Keep up the good work.

Comment: without any code, any example rows in your database and the expected result: no help :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Your post will need more information and a proper question if you want an answer. At the moment we don't have much to work with. Post your current solution, some example data and a clearly defined question to be answered.

Comment: Maybe this question helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080207/mysql-select-all-data-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1):

To add dates use `interval`. To convert a string to date use `str_to_date()`.
To check if a date is between two dates, use the `between` keyword.

```
select * from table_name
where date_columnname 
between str_to_date('2014-10-11','%y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 10 DAY
and str_to_date('2014-10-11','%y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 10 DAY
```