# Retrieve the result by a specific date between a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi friends I'm using MySQL. I would like to retrieve the result set by giving date in `WHERE` condition . I have given date range of the start date and end date . I have to compare the `date`[Today's] with the start date and end date .

for ex : 
`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 2015-07-22 is between start date and end date` .

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql: Select all data between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080207/mysql-select-all-data-between-two-dates)

Comment: Did you try `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE '2015-07-22' BETWEN start_date AND end_date`?

Comment: What is `oracle` tag doing here?

Comment: @Vatev Ya I have tried but returns error :-(

Comment: @user1894647 Any specific error?

Comment: @Vatev It returns #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEN start_date AND end_date LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Make sure the date constant (today's date) is in quotes (`'`). If that doesn't work post the whole query.

Comment: @user1894647 `BETWEEN` instead of `BETWEN`

Comment: @kulaeff Thanks a Lot It Works .

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE '2015-07-22' between start_date and end_date;
```

What I did:

1. Added quotes to date
2. removed "is" before between statement.